# How can I make my rooted Android 7 phone as secure as possible for financial transactions?

Tags: rooting, security, 7.0-nougat, antivirus, firewall

The latest security update patches for my phone was in 2017. My phone is rooted. What steps can I take to make it as secure as possible to be able to safely use financial apps where I'd be transacting money?

These apps need Google services to work, so custom roms are not an option (or are they?).

Comment: For background/context, OP's previous question: [Is a rooted phone safe for phone banking?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230442/44325)

Comment: if your device is Mediatek Chipset there is a risk for malware, therefore i recommend not to use banking apps at all https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit

Comment: Yes you can always install the google services in a custom rom. And why are you asking same question again and again?  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230442/is-a-rooted-phone-safe-for-phone-banking/230507#230507

Answer (score 0):

First of all install a stock rom of your mobile after that you can just do the banking transactions... Then go to google play store > setting > play protect certification > certified.

if the device is certified you can do any financial transactions!

Comment: I thought about that but I really need the phone rooted because I have some apps (like Titanum bu) that requires boot. What about dual boot?

Comment: The question was less "how can I use it for financial transactions" – but "how can I make it as safe as possible for financial transactions". Problem with "stock ROM" is, as the question pointed out, that the last security fix was 2017. Though providers of financial/banking apps do not care about that, it's not considered safe by security experts – while making it safe by installing a custom ROM is considered "unsafe" by most of those software vendors, so their apps refuse to run.

Comment: @Izzy the ones I got don't have a problem running on my rooted phone. There's also Magick hide as an open for those that do.